# Xamarin UITableVIew - Exapand and Collapse a row

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uipickerview

Using Xamarin for an iOS App, can someone give me some guidance on how to dynamically expand and collapse a particular table row.

My scenario is, a table with 2 rows one contains the text Venue, on click of this row I want to access the Row directly below which contains a PickerView (this Row's height gets set to 0 using GetHeightForRow) and expand its height to 261. My code for GetHeightForRow is:

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var someHeight = 44;

        if (RefineNames [indexPath.Row].Type == "Picker") {
            someHeight = 0;
        }

        return someHeight;
    }
```

I need the others rows all to remain at 44 and only to expand the Row which has the PickerView. Exactly like iOS7 Calendar App works when adding an Event.

This will also work in reverse to close the Row down.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You've already answered your own question.

UITableViewCells in a UITableView can be different subclasses and each can have a different height, just use different cellIdentifiers. If you change anything, just reload the data and the TableView will reflow the the cells.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your response, can you give me and example of accessing a cell by identifier?

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the whole row and adding it (collapse = removing, expand = adding).
The collapsing and expanding can be done by with animations (FadeIn/FadeOut).
I did that some time ago.
You just have to manage that in you list, so you have to remember the hidden items etc.